# How to interpret estimates and correlation of random effects (intercepts and slope) in a mixed-effects model in a Bayesian framework(brms)?

Tags: r, bayesian, mixed-model, random-variable

I do not understand how to interpret random slopes from the output of `brms`

Among others, I read [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/24452/how-to-interpret-variance-and-correlation-of-random-effects-in-a-mixed-effects-m) post on the output from `lmer`.
However instead of `Variance` in brms I have `Estimate`, as for fixed factor!!.
[This](https://www.rensvandeschoot.com/tutorials/brms-started/) page also helped me a bit.

In the following example the variable "experience.Mom" has a positive estimate at the group level (random slope) which, if I understand correctly is always the case (why??), and a negative effect at the population level. (intervals are over the 0 so no clear effect anyhow).

What does my random slope `Estimate` means? How does it influence my outcome variable (Y)?

## Group level (random)

```
                                              Estimate Est.Error l-95% CI u-95% CI Eff.Sample
sd(Intercept)                                     0.08      0.06     0.00     0.23       4323
sd(experience_Mom.z)                              0.09      0.06     0.00     0.24       4831
cor(Intercept,experience_Mom.z)                   0.00      0.57    -0.94     0.95       7528
```

## Population level (fixed)

```
                                                            Estimate Est.Error l-95% CI

experience_Mom.z                                               -0.02      0.09    -0.20
```

Answer (score 2):

In the output from **brms** you have posted the column `Estimate` gives you the estimates of the standard deviation of the random intercepts, the standard deviation of the random slopes, and the correlation between the intercepts and slopes. This corresponds to the second and third columns of the output you obtain from `lmer()` of **lme4** named `Std.Dev.` and `Corr`.

The interpretation of these numbers is nicely described in the first post you mentioned.